# People search in English, but site language is Foreign, what is the best approach to rank such sites?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, ranking, language

I am working on a news website, the articles are in foreign language, but the readers who look for the articles search the foreign language terms in English, the people who search for articles rarely search for the articles using keywords written in the foreign language.

So right now the sites that rank for these terms are English language websites, naturally because their keywords, title, content and meta contains it in English, whereas in our case, our article title, content, meta is all in the foreign language.

We have tried to add English and non English Foreign terms in English, the same way people search on Google or other search, but it won't help much.

Now i am trying to add an English excerpt to the news article, to see if that will help.

If there is any insight on this, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have reason to believe that the searchers using keywords in one language would find relevancy with results in another language that they weren't searching for? You give the impression that you are not referring to searches performed on and by your website.

Comment: Language targeting is tricky, I think we would need more information to address this properly. But I think if you are looking for an English speaking audience you should be writing articles in that language. The excerpt doesn't sound like enough to rank your pages on competitive news searches in USA and UK but you may have something else in mind.